# IKImageView and scrollToPoint: or scrollToRect:

Tags: objective-c, macos, imagekit, ikimageview

I'm trying to use IKImageView just because of the number of built-in features it offers. However, it also seems to provide built-in headaches as well. The latest of which is trying to programatically scroll via one of the documented methods:

```
- (void)scrollToPoint:(NSPoint)point
- (void)scrollToRect:(NSRect)rect
- setImageZoomFactor:centerPoint:
```

I have not been able to get any scrolling to occur. It is unclear which coordinate system these points or rectangles should be, so I tried a number of values and could never get it to do anything. Has anyone successfully used any of these? I was unable to find any example code, official or otherwise, that does this.

There is a decent bit of online chatter about scroll bars on an IKImageView and my quick experimentation seemed to prove why, it is really non-obvious/difficult. Though theoretically I could do this to programatically scroll.